# VBA for Excel - How to check intersection of ranges are not empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have two questions:
1) How do I check if  the intersection or a range is not empty? For example if I want to check if its empty I write for example

```
if application.intersect(r1,r2) is nothing
```

but is there something that is negation of nothing? not nothing didn't work for example.

2) How can I compate ranges? For example I have ranges r1,r2,r3 and I want to check if the intersection of r1 and r2 is r3. Two thing that I have tried and didn't work:

```
1 - application.intersect(r1,r2) = r3
2 - application.intersect(r1,r2) is r3
```

Would appreciate any help that I can get, Thanks!

Comment: put the not after the If: `if not application.intersect(r1,r2) is nothing`

Answer (score 4):

To see if the intersection of two ranges is a third range:

```
Set intRng =  Intersect(R1, R2)
If Not intRng Is Nothing then
    Set intRng =  Intersect(intRng, R3)
    If Not Intersect(intRng) Is Nothing
        If intRng.Address = R3.Address Then MsgBox "intersection of ranges R1 and R2 is range R3"
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if the intersection is empty you can use

```
If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Application.Intersect(rng1, rng2)) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "You Intersection is Empty!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

To see if 3 ranges intersect together is tougher.  Here's the logic

if a and b and c intersect than do something.

```
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Range("rg1"), Range("rg2")) 
Set fsect = Application.Intersect(Range("rg2"), Range("rg3")) 
Set gsect = Application.Intersect(Range("rg1"), Range("rg3")) 
if isect = True and fsect = Tru and gsect = True then
   '  They all intersect each other
   '  Put your code here
end if
```